# Find digits before string using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex expression that will retrieve the number `9018` which appears before `RT110539` in the following string:

```
<a href="?page=details&amp;skip=1">next</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<font color="#848484">1 / 9018&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;RT110539</font>
```

I am able to isolate the `RT110539` by using this regex expression: `(RT)\w+` but I cannot figure out what to use in order to isolate the number `9018` which appears immediately before.

Any suggestions please?  Thanks.

Comment: is the term 'RT110539' a fixed term, or will that change too according to some rules, ie, will it be RTXXXXXX, where X is number?

Comment: I would use something like `\b\d+(?=[^\d<]*RT\d+)` or (if `&nbsp;` is a space) `\b\d+(?=\s*RT\d+)`.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton the term will follow the RTXXXXXX pattern where X is a number.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev, your suggestion worked like a charm.  More importantly, now I can study your solution and learn from it.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @DanielAttard: I posted my comment since it worked for you, with some explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\b\d+(?=[^\d<]*RT\d+)
```

Or, if there are just spaces between the number and the RT code:

```
\b\d+(?=\s*RT\d+)
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/eP5oK6/1)  and [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/eP5oK6/2)

The `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), `\d+` matches 1 or more digits, `(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that makes sure there is something (`[^\d<]*` - 0 or more characters other than a digit or a `<` or `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace), then `RT` and 1 or more digits (`\d+`).

Answer (score -1):

```
 var patt = /\d\d\d\d\&nbsp/g ;
 var result = str.match(patt);
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please ?